# Resume object path rather than restarting path, how?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So I've created a collision detector function, that restarts the player object path when a collision is detected.
I'm trying to figure how to resume that path - start the path again from the point the player object hits.
What method should I be looking for to achieve this?

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {


var player = SKSpriteNode()
var bg = SKSpriteNode()

var topBoarder = SKSpriteNode()
var bottomBoarder = SKSpriteNode()
var rightBoarder = SKSpriteNode()
var leftBoarder = SKSpriteNode()

// Created a startPosition for my objects path.

let startPosition = CGPointMake(30, 30)

// The default value is 0, which means the game is not active.

var pathRunning = 0

// Defining different groups to be able to make them interact.

let boarderLineGroup:UInt32 = 1
let playerGroup:UInt32 = 2


// The functions that defines what will happen when doing swipes
// in the different directions.

// The player.removeActionForKey("trailRunning") stops the
// SKAction.repeatActionForever which is the path I created
// for my object. trailRunning is the KeyWord I created to
// manipulate whether the action should continue or not.

// applyImpulse makes it possible to, in this case, swipe the player
// object in a direction.

func swipedRight(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){

    player.removeActionForKey("trailRunning")
    pathRunning = 0
    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(10, 0))
}

func swipedLeft(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){

    player.removeActionForKey("trailRunning")
    pathRunning = 0
    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(-10, 0))
}

func swipedUp(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){

    player.removeActionForKey("trailRunning")
    pathRunning = 0
    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 10))
}

func swipedDown(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){

    player.removeActionForKey("trailRunning")
    pathRunning = 0
    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, -10))
}



override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */


    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self


    // Making swipes possible.

    var swipeRight:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedRight:"))
    swipeRight.direction = .Right
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)


    var swipeLeft:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedLeft:"))
    swipeLeft.direction = .Left
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)


    var swipeUp:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedUp:"))
    swipeUp.direction = .Up
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)


    var swipeDown:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedDown:"))
    swipeDown.direction = .Down
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)


    // Adding background.

    var bgTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bg")
    bg = SKSpriteNode(texture: bgTexture)
    bg.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    bg.size.height = self.frame.height
    bg.size.width = self.frame.width

    bg.zPosition = 1
    self.addChild(bg)


    // Adding boarder lines

    var topBoarderTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "topBoarder")
    topBoarder = SKSpriteNode(texture: topBoarderTexture)
    topBoarderPosition()

    topBoarder.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: topBoarder.size)
    topBoarder.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    topBoarder.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    topBoarder.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = boarderLineGroup
    topBoarder.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = playerGroup
    topBoarder.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = playerGroup

    topBoarder.zPosition = 2
    self.addChild(topBoarder)

    var bottomBoarderTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bottomBoarder")
    bottomBoarder = SKSpriteNode(texture: bottomBoarderTexture)
    bottomBoarder.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: 5)

    bottomBoarder.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bottomBoarder.size)
    bottomBoarder.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    bottomBoarder.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    bottomBoarder.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = boarderLineGroup
    bottomBoarder.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = playerGroup
    bottomBoarder.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = playerGroup

    bottomBoarder.zPosition = 2
    self.addChild(bottomBoarder)

    var leftBoarderTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "leftBoarder")
    leftBoarder = SKSpriteNode(texture: leftBoarderTexture)
    leftBoarder.position = CGPoint(x: 5, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

    leftBoarder.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: leftBoarder.size)
    leftBoarder.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    leftBoarder.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    leftBoarder.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = boarderLineGroup
    leftBoarder.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = playerGroup
    leftBoarder.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = playerGroup

    leftBoarder.zPosition = 2
    self.addChild(leftBoarder)

    var rightBoarderTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "rightBoarder")
    rightBoarder = SKSpriteNode(texture: rightBoarderTexture)
    rightBoarderPosition()

    rightBoarder.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: rightBoarder.size)
    rightBoarder.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    rightBoarder.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    rightBoarder.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = boarderLineGroup
    rightBoarder.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = playerGroup
    rightBoarder.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = playerGroup

    rightBoarder.zPosition = 2
    self.addChild(rightBoarder)


    // Adding player.

    var playerTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "player")
    player = SKSpriteNode(texture: playerTexture)
    player.position = startPosition

    // Defining the PhysicsBody, so I will be able to
    // make collision detection. The density will make it
    // possible for me to use something as applyForce().

    player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: player.size)
    player.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    player.physicsBody?.density = 1.0
    player.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = playerGroup
    player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = boarderLineGroup
    player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = boarderLineGroup

    player.zPosition = 10
    self.addChild(player)

}

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == boarderLineGroup || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == boarderLineGroup {

        println(">> Contact <<")
        if pathRunning == 0 {

            playerPath()
            pathRunning = 1

        }

    }
}

// playerPath is a function I made so that the path will be
// the same on every iPhone size.

func playerPath() {

    if frame.height == 480 {

        var movePlayerToBottomRight = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(290,30), duration: 1.5)
        var movePlayerToTopRight = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(290,450), duration: 2.5)
        var movePlayerToTopLeft = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(30,450), duration: 1.5)
        var movePlayerToStartPosition = SKAction.moveTo(startPosition, duration: 2.5)

        var playerTrail = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([movePlayerToBottomRight, movePlayerToTopRight, movePlayerToTopLeft, movePlayerToStartPosition]))

        player.runAction(playerTrail, withKey: "trailRunning")

    } else if frame.height == 568 {

        var movePlayerToBottomRight = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(290,30), duration: 1.5)
        var movePlayerToTopRight = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(290,538), duration: 2.5)
        var movePlayerToTopLeft = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(30,538), duration: 1.5)
        var movePlayerToStartPosition = SKAction.moveTo(startPosition, duration: 2.5)

        var playerTrail = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([movePlayerToBottomRight, movePlayerToTopRight, movePlayerToTopLeft, movePlayerToStartPosition]))

        player.runAction(playerTrail, withKey: "trailRunning")

    } else if frame.height == 667 {

        var movePlayerToBottomRight = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(345,30), duration: 1.5)
        var movePlayerToTopRight = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(345,637), duration: 2.5)
        var movePlayerToTopLeft = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(30,637), duration: 1.5)
        var movePlayerToStartPosition = SKAction.moveTo(startPosition, duration: 2.5)

        var playerTrail = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([movePlayerToBottomRight, movePlayerToTopRight, movePlayerToTopLeft, movePlayerToStartPosition]))

        player.runAction(playerTrail, withKey: "trailRunning")

    } else if frame.height == 736 {

        var movePlayerToBottomRight = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(384,30), duration: 1.5)
        var movePlayerToTopRight = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(384,706), duration: 2.5)
        var movePlayerToTopLeft = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(30,706), duration: 1.5)
        var movePlayerToStartPosition = SKAction.moveTo(startPosition, duration: 2.5)

        var playerTrail = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([movePlayerToBottomRight, movePlayerToTopRight, movePlayerToTopLeft, movePlayerToStartPosition]))

        player.runAction(playerTrail, withKey: "trailRunning")


    }

}

func topBoarderPosition() {

    if frame.height == 480 {

        topBoarder.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: 475)

    } else if frame.height == 568 {

        topBoarder.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: 563)

    } else if frame.height == 667 {

        topBoarder.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: 662)

    } else if frame.height == 736 {

        topBoarder.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: 731)

    }

}

func rightBoarderPosition() {

    if frame.height == 480 {

        rightBoarder.position = CGPoint(x: 315, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

    } else if frame.height == 568 {

        rightBoarder.position = CGPoint(x: 315, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

    } else if frame.height == 667 {

        rightBoarder.position = CGPoint(x: 370, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

    } else if frame.height == 736 {

        rightBoarder.position = CGPoint(x: 409, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

    }

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    // Here I tell that I have to press to start the game.

    if pathRunning == 0 {

        playerPath()

        // pathRunning set to 1 to show that the game is now active.

        pathRunning = 1
    }

}




override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

}
}
```

Comment: Did you try setting the `speed` property of the action to zero when you want to pause the action (when a collision is detected) and then set the `speed` to one to resume?

Comment: I'm not using the speed property. I will edit my code in, so you can see what I've done.

Comment: Besides, I did mange to make the path run again when collision is detected. The problem is, that it keeps going to the second point in the path, because it doesn't resume from the actual point it touches but instead from the start.